# typedef fixed length array

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, typedef

I have to define a 24-bit data type.I am using `char[3]` to represent the type. Can I typedef `char[3]` to `type24`? I tried it in a code sample. I put `typedef char[3] type24;` in my header file. The compiler did not complain about it. But when I defined a function `void foo(type24 val) {}` in my C file, it did complain. I would like to be able to define functions like `type24_to_int32(type24 val)` instead of `type24_to_int32(char value[3])`.

Answer (score 390, accepted):

The typedef would be

```
typedef char type24[3];
```

However, this is probably a very bad idea, because the resulting type is an array type, but users of it won't see that it's an array type. If used as a function argument, it will be passed by reference, not by value, and the `sizeof` for it will then be wrong.

A better solution would be

```
typedef struct type24 { char x[3]; } type24;
```

You probably also want to be using `unsigned char` instead of `char`, since the latter has implementation-defined signedness.

Comment: Is there any nice document which describes the corner cases involved with passing typedef'ed arrays as parameters?  For example, if a function takes a parameter `type24 foo`, what would be the sizes, types, and meanings of `foo`, `*foo`, `**foo`, `&foo`, and `&&foo`?  Have the meanings and legality of any such expressions changed over the years?

Comment: Probably worth mentioning the structure packing caveat, as a 24-bit data type might be intended to map to something with differently-defined packing semantics like RGB image data.

Comment: @sh1: On all modern real-world ABIs I'm aware of - even ones where misaligned access is very expensive - structures don't get stronger alignment requirements than their members would have without the structure. Of course OP or anyone else using this approach should verify my claim if it's going to matter to their program's behavior and portability.

Comment: Are there any problems when the name `type24` duplicates before and after `{ char x[3]; }`?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: No. The first is the struct tag and the second is the type name you're making with typedef.

Comment: @supercat I was also curious, so I made up an example where it goes wrong. I posted it below.

Comment: @R.. One part of this is misleading - in C, arrays are **always** passed by reference, i.e.,  if you modify the array passed as an argument to a function, you do so globally, not only in the context of the function. This being said, one could also argue that in C arrays are **always** being passed by value since we simply pass the address of the first element, which is copied onto the stack on the callee stack. In both cases, however, the answer is misleading.

Comment: Sadly for the _struct_ formtation, `sizeof(type24)` is unlikely to be 3. You'll probably need a few compiler dependent fixes. Fortunately you can ensure those fixes are used with a judicious `static_assert`.

Comment: @bobbogo: Have you checked this? I'm pretty sure it's 3 on all interesting targets.

Comment: It may be 3 on your targets. Presumably you have structure packing on in your compiler? Not portable though. Cygwin says `$ cat 1.cpp`:
`struct three { char three[3]; }; static_assert(sizeof(3) == 3, "urk");` and 
`$ g++ -std=c++11 1.cpp` gives
`1.cpp:2:1: error: static assertion failed: urk static_assert(sizeof(3) == 3, "urk");`

Comment: @bobbogo: That's not packing, it's just non-insertion of gratuitous padding. The alignment of the structure is just the maximum alignment of any of its members, all of which have alignment 1.

Comment: @bobbogo: Your test is buggy. `3` is an `int`, and `sizeof(int)!=3`.

Comment: @R. Yes you are right! A `struct` that has only `char` members will have no padding. I'm so used to the compiler adding padding to align longer types that I've missed this special case. Well, live and lean I suppose. (Oh, I _must_ read my own code—I wouldn't employ me :-).)

Comment: Well, that is the methods that help my to symplify binding with swig to C# a string. so thanks

Answer (score 65):

You want

```
typedef char type24[3];
```

C type declarations are strange that way.  You put the type exactly where the variable name would go if you were declaring a variable of that type.

Comment: i was expecting `typedef char[3] type24` but it looks like I was wrong :)). Is there any explaination why is it this way?

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu see the right-left rule for deciphering declarations: http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~ricko/rt_lt.rule.html

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu visit https://cdecl.org/ for translating between English and C

Answer (score 38):

From [R..'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4523537/1439843):

> However, this is probably a very bad idea, because the resulting type
>   is an array type, but users of it won't see that it's an array type.
>   If used as a function argument, it will be passed by reference, not by
>   value, and the sizeof for it will then be wrong.

Users who don't see that it's an array will most likely write something like this (which fails):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int twoInts[2];

void print(twoInts *twoIntsPtr);
void intermediate (twoInts twoIntsAppearsByValue);

int main () {
    twoInts a;
    a[0] = 0;
    a[1] = 1;
    print(&a);
    intermediate(a);
    return 0;
}
void intermediate(twoInts b) {
    print(&b);
}

void print(twoInts *c){
    printf("%d\n%d\n", (*c)[0], (*c)[1]);
}
```

It will compile with the following warnings:

```
In function ‘intermediate’:
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘print’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
    print(&b);
     ^
note: expected ‘int (*)[2]’ but argument is of type ‘int **’
    void print(twoInts *twoIntsPtr);
         ^
```

And produces the following output:

```
0
1
-453308976
32767
```

Answer (score 18):

Arrays can't be passed as function parameters by value in C.

You can put the array in a struct:

```
typedef struct type24 {
    char byte[3];
} type24;
```

and then pass that by value, but of course then it's less convenient to use: `x.byte[0]` instead of `x[0]`.

Your function `type24_to_int32(char value[3])` actually passes by pointer, not by value. It's exactly equivalent to `type24_to_int32(char *value)`, and the `3` is ignored.

If you're happy passing by pointer, you *could* stick with the array and do:

```
type24_to_int32(const type24 *value);
```

This will pass a pointer-to-array, not pointer-to-first-element, so you use it as:

```
(*value)[0]
```

I'm not sure that's really a gain, since if you accidentally write `value[1]` then something stupid happens.

Comment: I think this answer could be improved by mentioning the term `decay` somewhere (and maybe by pointing out that the situation is worse for *returning* arrays - which doesn't work at all).

Answer (score 8):

To use the array type properly as a function argument or template parameter, make a struct instead of a typedef, then add an `operator[]` to the struct so you can keep the array like functionality like so:

```
typedef struct type24 {
  char& operator[](int i) { return byte[i]; }
  char byte[3];
} type24;

type24 x;
x[2] = 'r';
char c = x[2];
```

Comment: This is a C question, not C++. Neither `char&` nor `operator[]` are things that exist in C.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a short example of why typedef array can be confusingly inconsistent.  The other answers provide a workaround.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef char type24[3];

int func(type24 a) {
        type24 b;
        printf("sizeof(a) is %zu\n",sizeof(a));
        printf("sizeof(b) is %zu\n",sizeof(b));
        return 0;
}

int main(void) {
        type24 a;
        return func(a);
}
```

This produces the output

```
sizeof(a) is 8
sizeof(b) is 3
```

because type24 as a parameter is a pointer.  (In C, arrays are always passed as pointers.)  The gcc8 compiler will issue a warning by default, thankfully.

Answer (score 4):

Building off the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4523537/7844823), a multi-dimensional array type, that is a fixed-length array of fixed-length arrays, can't be declared with

```c
typedef char[M] T[N];  // wrong!
```

instead, the intermediate 1D array type can be declared and used as in the accepted answer:

```c
typedef char T_t[M];
typedef T_t T[N];
```

or, `T` can be declared in a single (arguably confusing) statement:

```c
typedef char T[N][M];
```

which defines a type of `N` arrays of `M` chars (be careful about the order, here).