# Why did these variable apparently change type?

Tags: c, types, typedef

Python spoiled me and trying to wrap my mind around C now is being a bloodbath of stupid errors. This is one I can't quite understand.

I wanted the C equivalent of Python's [`os.path.split`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.split), but there's no exact equivalent. [`strsep`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strsep/) looks similar enough, but needs some massaging to be used simply.

First off, I defined my path type: a string of given length.

```
#define MAX_PATH_LEN 200 /* sigh */
typedef char t_path[MAX_PATH_LEN];
```

Then I wrote some code that does the actual massaging, attempting to avoid side effects -- just to keep things fool proof.

```
typedef struct {
    t_path next;
    t_path remainder;
} t_path_next

t_path_next path_walk_into(t_path path) {
    t_path_next output;

    t_path my_next, my_remainder = "/";
    strncpy(my_next, path, MAX_PATH_LEN);

    strsep(&my_next, my_remainder);

    output.remainder = my_remainder;
    output.next = my_next;
    return output;
}
```

gcc, however, is not impressed.

```
badp@delta:~/blah$ gcc path.c -Wall
path.c: In function ‘path_walk_into’:
path.c:39: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strsep’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/include/string.h:559: note: expected ‘char ** __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[200]’
path.c:41: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘t_path’ from type ‘char *’
path.c:42: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘t_path’ from type ‘char *’
```

I am baffled by the note -- how are `char **` and `char (*)[200]` really different -- but the error is even weirder. I want to assign a variable I declared `t_path` in a field of type `t_path`, but I don't get to.

Why is that?

---

For anybody interest here's the correctly working version of the function:

```
t_path_next path_walk_into(t_path path) {
    t_path_next output;
    t_path my_path, delim = "/";
    char* my_path_ptr = my_path;    
    strncpy(my_path, path, MAX_PATH_LEN);

    strsep(&my_path_ptr, delim); //put a \0 on next slash and advance pointer there.

    if (my_path_ptr == NULL) //no more slashes.
        output.remainder[0] = 0;
    else
        strncpy(output.remainder, my_path_ptr, MAX_PATH_LEN);
    strncpy(output.next, my_path, MAX_PATH_LEN);

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Part of the problem is that in C, arrays decay to pointers in various situations.  If you try using `char*` instead of `char[...]`, then you may get better results.  I haven't tried it, though :)

Comment: Using `typedef` with an array type is a sure formula or enraging everyone who ever reads your code and tries to figure out WTF it's doing. Just don't do that.

Comment: If the previous comment left you wondering (it did leave _me_ wondering), here's [an explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523497/typedef-fixed-length-array/4523537#4523537). It doesn't look like a particularly strong point to me (code will still work correctly), but it's a valid one still.

Comment: "how are `char **` and `char (*)[200]` really different" - the same way `char*` and `int*` are really different. They point to different things. The first points to a `char*` (and `strsep` is defined to store a pointer value into the location indicated by its first argument), the second points to a `char[200]`. Since an array is not the same thing as a pointer, it's no good passing a pointer to an array when what is needed is a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The errors: You can't directly assign to an array, such as a string, in C. You need to copy char by char, or call str(n)cpy, which does it for you.

Answer (score 3):

- For the warning : you are probably already aware that array may decay to pointer. That is, for example, what makes an array acceptable as an argument to a function where a pointer is expected. In your case, what you have is a pointer to an array : there is no reason for such a thing to get converted to a pointer to pointer.

  For the record, the C99 standard says (6.3.2.1/3) :

  > **Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary & operator**, or is a
  >   string literal used to initialize an array, **an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is
  >   converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’** that points to the initial element of
  >   the array object and is not an lvalue.

  You're in the context of a unary `&` : no conversion for you.
- For the error : it has already been answered, but array assignment is not directly possible. You might want to use `strcpy` or `strncpy`.

Comment: Thanks for that, so would an explicit cast suffice to change to the pointer to array to a pointer to pointer?

Comment: @badp: No. strsep expects a pointer to a pointer, so it can change that (second) pointer. Your variable my_next is a t_path, which is an array and not a pointer, so there _is_ no pointer for strsep to change!