# incompatible types when assigning to type ‘float[4]’ from type ‘float’ in c

Tags: c, types, incompatibletypeerror

I'm trying to copy values from an array of floats to a 4x4 floats matrix but keep getting this annoying error *"incompatible types when assigning to type ‘float[4]’ from type ‘float’"* please help me...

This is the typedef:

```
typedef float mat[4][4];
```

and then the function goes like this:

```
void function_Read(mat *matrixPointer, float *arrayOfFloats) {

    int indexOfArray;
    int rowIndexOfMatrix = 0;
    int columnIndexOfMatrix = 0;
    int sizeOfArrayOfFloats = sizeof (arrayOfFloats) / sizeof (arrayOfFloats[0]);

    for (indexOfArray = 0; indexOfArray < sizeOfArrayOfFloats; indexOfArray++) {
        /* the line below causes the error */
        matrixPointer[columnIndexOfMatrix][rowIndexOfMatrix] = arrayOfFloats[indexOfArray];

        columnIndexOfMatrix++;

        if (columnIndexOfMatrix == 4) {
            columnIndexOfMatrix = 0;
            rowIndexOfMatrix++;
        }
        if (rowIndexOfMatrix == 4) {
            rowIndexOfMatrix = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Plus, can someone add a link to a document for advanced pointers stuff in c ?
I'm always letting the debugger flash errors and then I correct them sometimes without even understanding the problem.

Thanks !

Comment: `mat *matrixPointer` is the problem.

Comment: Since `matrixPointer` is a `mat*`, you should access its elements through `(*matrixPointer)[col][row]` rather than `matrixPointer[col][row]`.

Comment: Also note that `sizeOfArrayOfFloats` doesn't hold the expected value, pointers are not arrays, etc...

Comment: float *ptr= arrayOfFloats; 
int count=0;

while ( *(ptr) != '\0' ) { ptr++; count++; }

That could be used to get you the length of the array.

Comment: The answer to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523497/typedef-fixed-length-array) explains what is going on.

Comment: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).