# Using typedef for an array to declare a new type

Tags: c

I know how to use typedef in order to define a new type (label).

For instance, `typedef unsigned char int8` means you can use "int8" to declare variables of type unsigned char.

However, I can't understand the meaning of the following statment:

```
typedef unsigned char array[10]
```

Does that mean array is of type unsigned char[10]?

In other part of code, this type was used as a function argument:

```
int fct_foo(array* arr)
```

Is there anyone who is familiar with this statement?

Comment: Your `int8` documents the intent - you will be storing small numbers, rather than a character. Also, typically the convention is `uint8_t` as declared in the C99 types.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Does that mean array is of type `unsigned char[10]`?

Replace *"of"* with *"another name for the"* and you have a **100% correct statement**. A `typedef` introduces a new name for a type.

```
typedef unsigned char array[10];
```

declares `array` as another name for the type `unsigned char[10]`, array of 10 `unsigned char`.

```
int fct_foo(array* arr)
```

says `fct_foo` is a function that takes a pointer to an array of 10 `unsigned char` as an argument and returns an `int`.

Without the `typedef`, that would be written as

```
int fct_foo(unsigned char (*arr)[10])
```

Comment: And it means that within the function `fct_foo`, the array will have to be used with `(*arr)[i]`, for example, to get at the `i`th character in the array.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer : what would be the argument type if above function is declared as `int fct_foo(array arr)'. ?  I am confused a bit here.

Comment: @Shivakumar Same as if you declared it `int fct_foo(unsigned char arr[10])`, as a function argument the array type is converted to a pointer type, so effectively the function is declared `int fct_foo(unsigned char *arr)`.

Comment: Nice though it is a bit hard to deduce `takes a pointer to an array of 10 unsigned char `

Answer (score 4):

What that does is it makes a datatype called `array` that is a fixed length array of 10 `unsigned char` objects in size.

[Here is a similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523497/typedef-fixed-length-array) that was asking how to do a fixed length array and that typedef format is explained in more depth.