# function return pointer to array type in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, gcc

The following piece of C code compiles under gcc 4.7, on a Debian (run with `gcc -c filename.c`)

```
typedef int array_type[3];
int a[] = {1,2,3};
int* asd1(void){
    return a;
}
array_type* asd2(void){
    return &a;
}
```

Instead of using the `typedef` I want to use the actual type. However, if I replace `array_type*` with something like `int*[3]` it doesn't compile.

What should I replace `array_type*` with to make it semantically the same as above and compile correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int (*asd2(void))[3]{
    return &a;
}
```

see [cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+%28*asd2%28void%29%29[3])

Comment: Bizarre it may appear but please check the [clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html). This is also one of the reason that [go's declaration syntax is different](http://blog.golang.org/gos-declaration-syntax)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int (*asd2(void))[3]{
     return &a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698256/using-typedef-for-an-array-to-declare-a-new-type).
And as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523497/typedef-fixed-length-array) you should not use such kind of typedef statements.

Comment: All I can say is that I have no choice but thanks for the links.