# Declaration of char array

Tags: c, arrays, char

I have seen a program, in the header file declared as below

```
typedef char CHAR10[10];
```

and in the program as below

```
CHAR10  szReading;
```

Is the above declaration same as

```
char szReading[10];
```

I am pretty much confused with these. Could someone explain what exactly it is?

Comment: Start by reading a good C book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you understand it correctly. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16698397/4354477) for more details.

When you say `CHAR10` would be the same as an array of char with fixed length and then say `CHAR10 test`, then `test` will certainly be an array of char of the length you want (10 in your example).

---

Examples of `typedef` usage

```
typedef unsigned int uint;
uint K; // K is an unsigned int

typedef char *SortOfString;
SortOfString test; // test is a pointer to char
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your interpretation is correct.

Comment: If i want to declare double array can i do `CHAR10 szReading[5]` is that correct?

Comment: Yes. That would be equivalent to `char szReading[5][10]`. I'm not sure if that's what you mean by 'double array', though. IMHO it would be better to not hide important information with `typedef` in this manner.

Comment: @Yes I meant to say 2D array, Thanks

Comment: @Aravind: You need to be careful with the word "double". This: `double arr[5];` is a `double` array.