# how do I typedef struct <name> *var_name[32]

Tags: c, syntax, typedef, c99

One of my C functions takes the following as it first argument

```
struct list *items[32]
```

how do I make a `typedef` for this?

Comment: Possibly answered at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523497/typedef-fixed-length-array

Comment: That help me find the answer

Comment: I think you can answer your own question. It can be helpful for anyone who comes later. Or, we should just vote for close this Q as duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is `typedef struct list* ProcList[32];`