# Incompatible pointer type warning with const array parameter

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

My understanding is that

```
char (*)[20]
```

is a [pointer to an array of 20 **non-const chars**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/859650/1611055), while

```
const char (*)[20]
```

is a pointer to an array of 20 **const chars**.

In the following code, I am passing a pointer to an array of **non-const chars** to a function which expects a pointer to an array of **const chars**. Inside the function, the compiler properly catches write accesses to the array, as expected:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void f(const char (*param)[20]) {
   /* correctly catched by the compiler: assignment of read-only location '(*param)[2]' */
   /* (*param)[2] = 'A'; */
}

int main() {
   char (*data)[20] = calloc(20, 1);

   f(data);

   return 0;
}
```

However, I am getting the following warning at the function call:

```
$ gcc -Wall -pedantic -o so so.c
so.c: In function 'main':
so.c:15:4: warning: passing argument 1 of 'f' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
    f(data);
    ^
so.c:3:6: note: expected 'const char (*)[20]' but argument is of type 'char (*)[20]'
 void f(const char (*param)[20]) {
      ^
```

Why is that? Should it not always be possible to pass a **pointer to non-const data** to a function which expects a **pointer to const data** of the same type?

I know that there are [other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523497/typedef-fixed-length-array) to this, but I am particularly interested in understanding why the compiler gives this warning in this specific situation.

Comment: I'm not sure if this makes any difference to the resoning, but `const char (*)[20]` is a pointer to an array of 20 `const char`. An array is its elements, so it is hard to imagine what a `const` array with non-const elements would be.

Comment: `clang a.c -Wall -pedantic` gives no warning at all.

Comment: @juanchopanza Maybe my phrasing was not choosen too well :-) - essentially the question is why I get this warning when passing a pointer to writable memory to a function which expects read-only memory. IMHO it should always be possible in that direction (of course **not** the other way round...)

Comment: This seems ok, syntactically: http://ideone.com/kOukUX

Comment: For what is worth, the same code with G++ does not emit the warning.

Comment: @rodrigo Which version of `g++` are you using? I've tried `g++ 4.9.1` and it gives an error at line 9 saying invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char (*)[20]’

Comment: @starrify: Well, I patched that part that is obviously non-C++-ish. BTW, it is G++ 4.8.2.

Comment: Please, see [this GCC FAQ](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FAQ#constmismatch). TLDR: "This is how C works".

Comment: @rodrigo Excellent - the linked [C FAQ](http://archive.today/mGvX7) boils it down to the fact that you **can** assign `T*` to `const T*`, but **not** `T**` to `const T**` (at any pointer level > 1). It also says "The reason ... is somewhat obscure" - well, yes ... Anyway, if you like, post an answer and I will be happy to accept it!

Comment: @Andreas: Oh my! The question has been closed as duplicated while I was writing!! Well... that's SO.

Comment: @rodrigo Yes, just saw it, sorry for that - I did not find the duplicate answer before, maybe I was too focused on "passing as parameter" ...