# Return sorted array with void function to find median

Tags: c++, arrays, unix, void, median

so I am writing this program that reads user input into an array and then finds the mean and median. I have three different files that I am going to compile together in unix:
1) stats.h, which contains the prototypes that I was given for my mean, median, and sort functions
2) stats.cpp, where I am supposed to implement these three functions, and
3) main.cpp, with my main function.

So far, my main() is functioning correctly. There are two main issues that I am having:

1) I want to make sure that I am passing the array[] and its size correctly to each of the three functions (I'm a little rusty on passing arrays).
2) I was given the prototypes for my three functions (including the void Sort function) and I was told to call the Sort function in the Median function.

I don't really understand how to update the old array in the Median function if I can't return the sorted array in the Sort function (if that makes sense).

So here are my three files:
1) stats.h

```
//not sure if I need to include anything at top
float Mean (const int* array, size_t size);
float Median (int* array, size_t size);
void Sort (int* array, size_t size);
```

2) stats.cpp

```
#include <stats.h>  //only include header file with prototypes?
//function to find the mean that should be called by
main()                                         
float Mean (int NewArray[], size_t size)
{                                                                    
   float sum, mean = 0.0;          

   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {                           
      sum += NewArray[i];                                
   }                                         
   mean = ((float)sum)/size;

   return mean;                                   
}

//function to find median that should be called by main()
float Median (int NewArray[], size_t size);
{//not sure how to call sort (void) function and return new sorted array to median function

    if(size % 2 == 0)                                            
    {                      
      median = (NewArray[size/2] + NewArray[size/2-1])/2.0f;
    }                                               
    else            
    {                                                  
      median = NewArray[size/2];                        
    }                                                                      
 return median;  //return median to main()                 
} 

// void function to sort array in ascending order and called by median()
Sort(int NewArray[], size_t size)                    
{                                               
   for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {                                                    
      for(int j = 0; j < size-1; j++)                          
      {                           
         if(NewArray[j] > NewArray[j+1])             
         {
             int temp = NewArray[j+1];                  
             NewArray[j+1] = NewArray[j];            
             NewArray[j] = temp;               
          }
       }
    }
}
```

3) And main()

```
#include <iostream>                                
#include <stats.h>                           
#include <stats.cpp>                  

int main()                                      
{                                              
    int input, sum, NumberOfEntries = 0;     
    const int SIZE = 100                      

    int array[SIZE];                               

    std::cout << "Please enter integers ('x' to quit): ";

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)    
    {                            
       if (std::cin >> array[i])               
       {                                             
       }
       else                                        
       {                                      
          NumberOfEntries = i;                  
          break;                                    
       }                                                    
    }                                             

    std::cout << "Data as entered: ";                
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfEntries; i++)     
       std::cout << array[i] << " ";    

    std::cout << "Mean: " << float Mean (array[SIZE], NumberOfEntries);

    std::cout << "Median: " << float Median (array[SIZE], NumberOfEntries);

    std::cout << "Data after sort: "; //would print out sorted array 

    return 0;                                    
}
```

Comment: This is a QA site. What's your question?

Comment: Save yourself and everybody effort by using `std::vector` instead of arrays.  The vectors are easier to pass to functions and they can be accessed like arrays.

Comment: You have two `main` functions, one in `main` and one in `stats`.  You are only allow one.  Pick one and rename the other (or get rid of it).

Comment: Also, your function, variable and class names should differ in more than just case.  For example, "Mean" and "mean" should be different.  The function name could be "Calculate_Mean".

Comment: Your function declarations are not requiring arrays, but pointers to **single** integer.  The data type, pointer to an integer, means that the pointer could point to a single integer anywhere and there doesn't have to be any integers following it.  For tips on how to declare a function requiring an array, search the web for "c++ typedef array".

Answer (score 0):

You should create a synonym for an array (which makes passing easier):

```
typedef int DataArray[/* Some size constant*/];
```

(See [StackOverflow question about array typedef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523497/typedef-fixed-length-array))

You can declare your functions as:

```
double Calculate_Mean(const Data_Array array, unsigned int size);
double Calculate_Median(const Data_Array array, unsigned int size);
```

By the way, unless you need to conserve space, use `double`, not float.  Most of the libraries in C++ that use floating point use the `double` type.  It's more accurate.

Also, use `unsigned int` for quantities.  I have yet to see an array that is -5 in length.  The `unsigned` keyword will help the compiler check for negative values assigned to indices and quantities (Hmm, can you purchase -5 apples?).