# How to create pointer to 2D array in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I have a 2D array like this and I want a pointer to it.

Currently I have this:

```
char* recv_args_msg_queue[20];
char** ref_temp = &recv_args_msg_queue[0];
char*** ref_queue = &ref_temp;
```

But I feel my way is really dumb. Is there a way to do it on one line?

**Note:**

`char* recv_args_msg_queue[20];` is later in my code allocated properly to be an array. I just wanted dynamic allocation otherwise I could have wrote:

`char recv_args_msg_queue[20][another_number_here];`

Comment: Where's the 2D array?!?

Comment: `char* recv_args_msg_queue[20];`

Comment: Do you properly allocate it? I mean, each of the 20 (dynamic) subarrays?

Comment: Pointers are not arrays. Arrays are not pointers. War is peace. Slavery is freedom. Little-endian is big-endian.

Comment: @TheCrafter , that is a pointer to a pointer. **It is not a 2D array**. If you try to access it like a 2D array, you will get a Segmentation Fault.

Comment: @Antonio Yes later in my code. That should not be a problem with my question.

Comment: `char* recv_args_msg_queue[20];` is not a 2D array -- it's an array of 20 `char` pointers.

Comment: `char* array_of_chars` is a pointer to a char. From there you can start a char array. Thus, `char** array_of_char_ptrs` is a pointer to a char*. From there you can start an array of char*. Am I wrong?

Comment: @TheCrafter , "*`char* array_of_chars` is a pointer to a char. From there you can start a char array*". If you include `[` and `]`, it becomes "an array of pointer to `char`"

Comment: In practice, don't do that. In C code, always prefer 1D arrays.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I want to implement something like a queue for strings. I did not see another way to do it.

Comment: Use several `struct`, some of them containing a [flexible array member](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I write my program with ANSI C Standard not C99. I should have stated that earlier.

Comment: @TheCrafter: I believe that you are wrong in using such an obsolete standard for C. And if it is a requirement, you should have explicitly stated that (you need an ANSI C way, not a C99 way). Then you could use 0-sized array in `struct`  instead of flexible array members.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It is not a commercial project. It is a personal one. I believe that one must learn how to walk before how to run. If I want to understand fully C99 and later C++, I feel I have to experience some ANSI C too. I will look into your 0-sized array. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a [typedef for your array type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523497/typedef-fixed-length-array) will make easier getting a pointer to it.

Your code would look like this:

```
typedef char* msg_queue20[20];

msg_queue20 recv_args_msg_queue;
msg_queue20* ref_queue = &recv_args_msg_queue;
```

Take care of reading the link I posted, as it contains [important recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4523537/2436175).

Comment: You are right. I defined `typedef char** char_ar_2d;` and then I could get a pointer.