# How to create an automatic array[N] on the heap, with new

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, new-operator

I have a corner case with regards to pointers and arrays.

How do I allocate a fixed-size (automatic) array on the heap? Let's get to the code right away to understand what I'm trying to ask:

```
typedef int ArrayOf10Ints[10];

int f()
{
        ArrayOf10Ints * p = new ArrayOf10Ints; // Error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'ArrayOf10Ints *'
                                               // (aka 'int (*)[10]') with an rvalue of type 'int *'

        ArrayOf10Ints * q = new ArrayOf10Ints[1] // OK: allocates space for 10 ints

        delete q; // Warning: use delete []
}
```

Why doesn't the expression to allocate `p` work? Why is the rvalue an `int*` and not a `ArrayOf10Ints*`? And why does `q` work?

Note: my goal is to understand the unexpected behavior allocating `p` and `q`. As others have pointed out there are many straightforward ways to solve this problem. For example, in my case, I'm using a pointer to denote that the array is optional—it may or may not exist—so I would do this instead:

```
boost::optional<std::array<int, 10> > optional_array;
```

Comment: You don't! Use a [standard container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: When trying to allocate `p`, you get an error saying _cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘int (*)[10]’ in initialization_. As you defined the type `ArrayOfTenInts`, it is a pointer to memory area consisting of 10 integers (a 40-bit data type), so `int*`. Also, this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523497/typedef-fixed-length-array

Comment: Specifically use `std::array<int,10>`

Comment: _"Note: for reasons beyond this discussion, I need to do exactly this."_ Elaborate about that restriction please. What are the parts you cannot change actually? The typedef?

Comment: Also note we don't do _"discussions"_ here. Stack Overflow _isn't a forum_.

Comment: You're right, I've edited my question to clarify my intent and make clear for other readers that there're better solutions to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a behavior of `new` that is somewhat surprising. Even though `ArrayOf10Ints` is an alias for `int[10]`, when you use it in a `new` expression, the result is as if you were writing `new int[10]` instead.

This is specified in [*[expr.new]/5*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#5)

> **When the allocated object is an array (that is,** the *noptr-new-declarator* syntax is used or the *new-type-id* or ***type-id* denotes an array type), the *new-expression* yields a pointer to the initial element (if any) of the array.**

So in your example, the `new` expression returns an `int *`, hence the error.

A workaround is to do what you've shown

```
ArrayOf10Ints* q = new ArrayOf10Ints[1];
delete[] q;
```

or place the array in a `struct`, or use `std::array`.

Note that even if you were to write

```
int* p = new ArrayOf10Ints;
```

you must then use `delete[] p` because `operator new[]` is called in this case too.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a08bc901567b24f8)

Answer (score 0):

> Note: for reasons beyond this discussion, I need to do exactly this

Certainly not, because wrong things don't work.

Use a `std::array<int,10>` instead. This code should work just smoothly:

```
typedef array<int,10> ArrayOf10Ints;

int f() {
     ArrayOf10Ints * p = new ArrayOf10Ints;
     // ...

     delete p;
}
```

---

However I won't recommend you manage `new` and `delete` yourself, unless you're absolutely sure you need to.

Comment: Believe me, if I could, I'd use boost::optional<std::array<int, 10> >

Comment: @alexc If you don't have access to the current c++11 standard, roll your own version of the `std::array` template, it's pretty straightforward and simple. If you are using something like Turbo C++, you're beyond of all hopes.

Comment: It's not just potential older compilers. I'm dealing with a system where I can't make such changes. My goal here is to understand why p doesn't work and q does.

Comment: @alexc What _changes_ actually? The `typedef` is predefined by legacy code, and you need to make use of it?