# why "passing argument of incompatible pointer type" warning

Tags: c, gcc, warnings

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef float FloatArray[5];

static void doSomething(const FloatArray* i_data){
  (void)i_data;
}


int main(void){
  FloatArray fa = {1,2,4,5,6};
  doSomething(&fa);
  return 0;
}
```

I get the following warning and i do not understand why

> passing argument 0 of 'doSomething' from incompatible pointer type

If I remove the `const` from the function argument then the warning disappears.

gcc is called with

> -c -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wfloat-conversion -Wenum-compare -Wshadow -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wredundant-decls -Winline -Wnested-externs -pedantic -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523497/typedef-fixed-length-array

Comment: @MichaelVeksler I'm not following you. `&fa` *is* a pointer to an array.

Comment: @sepp2k you are right. I don't know how I missed that &