# What is the correct placement of names and types in the typedef syntax?

Tags: c++, c++17, typedef

Usually the syntax of typedef is as follows

```
typedef <existing_name> <new_name>
```

But in the following case, I am bit confused

```
  typedef char yes[1];
  typedef char no[2];
```

This above seems to work. Why and how?

Shouldn't this be written as below?

```
  typedef yes char[1];
  typedef no char[2];
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523497/typedef-fixed-length-array

Comment: The syntax is exactly the same as in variable declarations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Usually the syntax of typedef is...

No, that's not accurate. The usual syntax is

```
typedef <variable declaration>;
```

Then the declaration is decomposed, and the *name* of the variable becomes a new name for the type the variable would have had. The case you are confused about is inline with that. In the absence of `typedef`, that's how you'd declare an array variable. Add a `typedef`, and the variable name becomes a new name for the type.

Of course, a modern type alias will actually look more like what you expect

```
using yes = char[1];
using no  = char[2];
```

Which is good in the sense that it doesn't require one to understnad C++'s declarator syntax just to see what the name of the type is. One still has to understand the syntax to write the type on the right hand side, though...

Comment: At least now I know why `using` was introduced :)