# Taking address of fixed-size-array argument seemingly fails. Why?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, typedef, implicit-conversion, function-declaration

I am playing with example code provided in one of the answers to
[typedef fixed length array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523497/typedef-fixed-length-array) .

The answer only states that the code fails, but does not explain, why. Could anyone provide an explanation?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int twoInts[2];

void print(twoInts *twoIntsPtr);
void intermediate (twoInts twoIntsAppearsByValue);

int main () {
    twoInts a;
    a[0] = 0;
    a[1] = 1;
    print(&a);
    intermediate(a);
    return 0;
}

void intermediate(twoInts b) {
    printf("im1: %d, %d\n", b[0], b[1]);
    print(&b);
    printf("im2: %d, %d\n", b[0], b[1]);
}

void print(twoInts *c){
    printf("pr: %d, %d\n", (*c)[0], (*c)[1]);
}
```

Compiling this produces the following warnings:

```
a.c: In function ‘intermediate’:
a.c:19:11: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘print’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   19 |     print(&b);
      |           ^~
      |           |
      |           int **
a.c:5:21: note: expected ‘int (*)[2]’ but argument is of type ‘int **’
    5 | void print(twoInts *twoIntsPtr);
      |            ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
```

And the output is:

```
pr: 0, 1
im1: 0, 1
pr: 1854416416, 32767
im2: 0, 1
```

What I can't understand is why the "pr" lines differ. After all - both `a` and `b` have type `twoInts` and both produce same results when index operator (`[]`) is applied.

========== UPDATE ===========

I now realize that what I'm really interested in is what the actual value (actual bytes) does the argument `c` has?

Let's say we have the following memory layout:

The original array is located at memory address 150:

```
m[150]=0
m[154]=1
```

Argument `b` is in stack and has (let's say) address 140. My understanding is that it has type `int*` and therefore probably holds address of first element of the array:

```
m[140]=150  // argument b
```

Calling the print() from `main()` will probably put the argument `c` at the very same address, but I'm not sure about the value:

```
m[140]=?    // argument c, print() is called directly from main()
```

Calling the print() from `intermediate()` will put argument `c` at even earlier address, but would the value be 140 - the address of argument `b`?

```
m[130]=?    // argument c, print() called from intermediate()
```

Comment: The typedef (as is the case 98% of the time) is confusing things.  If you write `void intermediate(int *b)` and `void intermediate2(int c[2])`, what is the difference?  What is the type of `c`?

Comment: Alexey Nezhdanov, for more clarity, print the pointer: `printf("im1: %d, %d\n", b[0], b[1]);` --> `printf("im1: %p, %d, %d\n", (void*)b, b[0], b[1]);`  and `printf("pr: %d, %d\n", (*c)[0], (*c)[1]);` --> `printf("pr: %p %p %d, %d\n", (void*) c,  (void*) *c,  (*c)[0], (*c)[1]);`.

Answer (score 2):

A function parameter that has an array type is adjusted by the compiler to pointer to the array element type.

So this function declaration

```
void intermediate (twoInts twoIntsAppearsByValue);
```

is adjusted by the compiler to the declaration

```
void intermediate ( int * twoIntsAppearsByValue);
```

Within the function

```
void intermediate(twoInts b) {
    printf("im1: %d, %d\n", b[0], b[1]);
    print(&b);
    printf("im2: %d, %d\n", b[0], b[1]);
}
```

there is used this statement

```
print(&b);
```

where the argument expression has the type `int **` while the corresponding parameter of the function has the type `int ( * )[2]`.

```
void print(twoInts *c){
    printf("pr: %d, %d\n", (*c)[0], (*c)[1]);
}
```

These pointer types are not compatible and the compiler shall issue a corresponding message.

In the function `intermediate` the expression `&b` points to its local variable (parameter) `b`.

In the call of the function `print` in main

```
print(&a);
```

the expression `&a` points to the original array.

Here is a demonstration program that shows the difference.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int twoInts[2];

int main( void )
{
    twoInts a = { [0] = 0, [1] = 1 };

    twoInts *p1 = &a;

    int *p2 = a;
    int **pp2= &p2;

    printf( "*p1 = %p\n", ( void * )*p1 );
    printf( "*pp2 = %p\n", ( void * )*pp2 );
    printf( "*( int ( * )[2] )pp2 = %p\n", ( void * )*( int ( * )[2] )pp2 );
    printf( "&p2 = %p\n", ( void * )&p2 );
}
```

The program output might look like

```
*p1 = 0x7ffef35980c8
*pp2 = 0x7ffef35980c8
*( int ( * )[2] )pp2 = 0x7ffef35980c0
&p2 = 0x7ffef35980c0
```

So you got the ouput

```
pr: 1854416416, 32767
```

because the address of the parameter `b` was considered as the address of the array itself.

Comment: Thank you! You seem to imply that the runtime value of argument `c` is the address of the first element of the array (when called correctly) - did I understand you right?

I have now updated my question with a mocked example of address space to illustrate the idea - so I expect the argument `c` to contain address of the array (150) when called directly from `main()` and address of argument `b` (140) when called the second time. Is that correct?

Comment: @AlexeyNezhdanov The values of expressions a and &a are the same but has different types. Calling the function print in main you are passing the address of the array. Calling the function print inside another function using the expression &b you are passing the address of the pointer b.

Answer (score 0):

I have played with my program a bit more and discovered two interesting properties:

1. if I print the pointer that `print()` function receives then it is (unsurprisingly) differs between two invocations, the second pointer holding smaller address than the first (also somewhat unsurprisingly).
2. if I remove the address-taking in the `intermediate()` function and just call `print(b);` then the pointers become the same and therefore the output also becomes the same:

```c
void intermediate(twoInts b) {
    printf("im1: %d, %d\n", b[0], b[1]);
    print(b);
    printf("im2: %d, %d\n", b[0], b[1]);
}
```

Output:

```
pr: 0, 1
im1: 0, 1
pr: 0, 1
im2: 0, 1
```

While this is not really an answer to my question, this still provides enough insight.

The `b` seems to be interpreted sometimes as `int*` and sometimes as `int**` - all within the same function. Therefore when I was taking address of it, it was effectively producing `int***`.

So I guess I should be grateful that it didn't segfault at `(*c)[1])`.

Comment: C typedefs do not change the behavior of C arrays passed as a parameter to a function. Arrays passed to a function "decay" to a pointer to the first element of the array. The size of the array is not implicitly passed when an array pointer is passed to a function.

Comment: This size obviously won't be passed so it is unknown at runtime. However I expect the compiler to know the size and that's why I wanted to use fixed-size array in the first place.