# Is there a way to differentiate pointer and reference to an array inside a structure?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

Say I have a structure:

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t *ptr;
    /* array_reference is a reference to an array, not a pointer to a singular variable */
    uint8_t *array_reference;
}  weird_struct_t;
```

and ptr field is used as a pointer to uint8_t variable, but array_reference is used as array that's declared somewhere else.

Is there a way to tell compiler that array_reference field is an array so it's not used in a way above?

In total:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t some_numbers[7] = {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13};
uint8_t other_numbers[] = {21, 34, 55};

typedef struct {
    uint8_t *ptr;
    /* array_reference is a reference to an array, not a pointer to a singular variable */
    uint8_t *array_reference;
}  weird_struct_t;

int main()
{
    uint8_t a = 89;
    weird_struct_t ws1 = {&a, some_numbers};
    weird_struct_t ws2 = {&a, other_numbers};

    printf("%u, %u, %u, %u\n", *ws1.ptr, *ws1.array_reference, *ws2.ptr, *ws2.array_reference);

    return 0;
}
```

I know array is a pointer as well, but maybe there's a way to let user or compiler know ptr and array_reference fields are not the same types.

Comment: No, there's no way to tell what a pointer points to.

Comment: You can make a `struct Array { size_t reserved; size_t used; uint8_t *data; };` and point to it. Point to the whole `struct` not simply the data or you can even make it an **opaque data type** :-)

Comment: @pmg That just pushes the problem down a level, you can't prevent them from using `*ws2.array_reference->data`

Comment: You might try using `typedef` to define a type for the specific array you need, and making the pointer to that type. I found a discussion on using `typedef` for arrays here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523497/typedef-fixed-length-array

Comment: And the typedef part of that is optional, @JohnBayko.  But note well that using the resulting pointer requires different syntax than using the pointed-to array itself (or the pointer to which it decays).  And also that the array length is baked into a pointer-to-array type, which has both advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>      /* array_reference is a reference to an array, not a pointer to a singular variable */
> ```

In the first place, no, `array_reference` is *not* a reference to an array, because C does not have references.  It may be a pointer to an array *element*, perhaps the first element of its host array, but that is not the same thing.

And to the extent that you may say you understand that already, you seem to be drawing a distinction that C doesn't.  From C's point of view, a pointer to a scalar object is for all intents and purposes equivalent to a pointer to the first element of a one-element array.

> I know array is a pointer as well,

**Arrays are not pointers.**  This is absolutely essential to understand.  An array is a composite object comprising one or more other objects (its elements) arranged contiguously in memory.  Lvalues of array type are automatically *converted to* pointers in many (not all) contexts, but arrays themselves are not pointers.  Perhaps that "array is a pointer" nonsense is how you formed the misconception that C has references.  C does not have references.  And arrays are not pointers.

> but maybe there's a way to let user or compiler know ptr and array_reference fields are not the same types.

But they *are* the same type (`uint8_t *`), and the objects they point to are the same type, too (`uint8_t`).

Now, it is possible to define a pointer to a whole array ...

```
uint8_t array[42];
uint8_t (*ap)[42] = &array;
```

... and sometimes that's useful, but the syntax for usage of such pointer types is a bit different from the syntax for using arrays (or the pointers to which they decay) directly.

You can also declare structure members as arrays rather than pointers, of course, but that's different.

Overall, as far as

> Is there a way to differentiate pointer and reference to an array inside a structure?

, the best reframing I can come up with that makes sense to me, is "is there a way to determine how many elements can be accessed via a pointer?" (being inside a structure has nothing to do with it).  The answer is that if you need such information then you need to track it yourself.  The pointers themselves do not tell you that, except inasmuch as null pointers definitely do not provide access to any elements at all.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to tell compiler that array_reference field is an array
> ...
> maybe there's a way to let user or compiler know ptr and array_reference fields are not the same types

`uint8_t (*array_reference)[3];` declares a pointer to an array of exactly 3 elements. It is not compatible with `uint8_t*`. So that would be exactly what you are asking for.

If changing the struct like that, then `weird_struct_t ws1 = {&a, some_numbers};` won't compile and you'll have to do `&some_numbers`.

*However*, this sounds a bit like an "XY problem". The user of a struct should know the purpose of each struct member, or they shouldn't be using it. Most often the "user" is just the module where that struct is declared. If it is to be used beyond that, then the proper solution is either to document how each member should be used, or as suggested in a comment, make the struct "opaque type" so that none can access it's members outside the .c file dealing with the internals.

Example of how to implement opaque types here: [How to do private encapsulation in C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/283888)